# Where clause with multiple values in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to make a report for the bus transport system, the report's form has "Driver" and "Route" fields. It works fine when I select "Driver" to get a report or select only "Route" to get the report, but there is something wrong when I choose both "Driver and Route." Any assistance would be appreciated

**View/Form**

```php
<form action="" method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <label>From Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="start" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <label>To Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="end" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="route_content">
            <label>Route</label>
            <select name="routeid" id="route_id" class="js-example-placeholder-singleuserid js-states form-control"
                    style="width: 100%; height:40px;">
                <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($routes as $key => $value): ?>
                <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->from}} -> {{$value->to}}</option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="driver_content" z>
            <label>Driver</label>
            <select name="driverid" id="driver_id" class="js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control"
                    style="width: 100%; height:40px;">
                <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($driver as $key => $value): ?>
                <option value="{{$value->id}}"> {{$value->name}} </option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" style="margin-top: 27px;">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
 Route::get('post_genral_report/{start?}/{end?}' , 
'reportController@post_genral_report')->name('abd');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function post_genral_report(Request $request, $start = null, $end = null)
{
    $data = DB::table('registration_tickets')
        ->join('trips', 'trips.id', 'registration_tickets.trip_id')
        ->join('buses', 'buses.id', 'trips.bus_id')
        ->join('drivers', 'drivers.id', 'trips.driver_id')
        ->join('routes', 'routes.id', 'trips.route_id')
        ->join('provinces as p1', 'p1.id', 'routes.from')
        ->join('provinces as p2', 'p2.id', 'routes.to')
        ->select('registration_tickets.*', 'p1.name as from', 'p2.name as to', 'buses.type', 'buses.plate',
            'drivers.name as d_name', 'drivers.lastname as lname');

    if ($start and $end) {
        $data->whereBetween('registration_tickets.date', [
            $start,
            $end
        ]);
    }

    if ($request->driverid) {
        $data->where('trips.driver_id', $request->driverid);
    }

    if ($request->routeid) {
        $data->where('trips.route_id', $request->routeid);

    }

    if ($request->driverid and $request->routeid) {
        $data->where([
            'trips.driver_id', '=', $request->driverid,
            'trips.route_id', '=', $request->routeid
        ]);
    }

    $data = $data->get();

    return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
}
```

Comment: You do not need `if ($request->driverid and $request->routeid) {
            $data->where([
                 'trips.driver_id', '=' , $request->driverid,
                 'trips.route_id', '=' ,  $request->routeid
            ]);
          }`.
Because if you enter both the value code above would already apply both conditions. Just try with removing this part.

Comment: _"Something wrong"_ what is wrong?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada I removed this part as you said. but nothing's changed,

Comment: @Viney as I said it works fine when I get report separately, for example I want to get report just for "Driver" or Just for "Route" , but when I select both It doesn't work properly and kind of ignore Driver and it sort just for "Route"

Comment: @Reza. Are you getting any values when both are selected before return?

Comment: someone upvoted even he doesn't get the question

Comment: @DhananjayKyada it tried dd(); , but it didn't work for me 
this is the URL : get_genral_report?start=2019-03-01&end=2019-06-25&routeid=4&driverid=1

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari don't know what is happening, but maybe he/she has the same problem

Comment: @Reza. Are you sure that there is at least one record present which satisfies both the condition? Please check it first.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada  I've been checking for a week..
I have a trip with a "Route : abc" and "Driver :def" , When both of them are selected, both conditions must apply. but it ignores Driver name, I mean doesn't matter which driver u select it just return by Route. 
I hope u got what I'm saying

Comment: @Reza. Please upload database tables here. So that we can help you.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada I want to insert migration code but doesn't accept

Comment: @DhananjayKyada trip table: id , bus_id, route_id, driver_id, date, start_time
registrationticket : id , trip_id, user_id .....

Answer (score 2):

> You need to modify the part where you are using both driver_id and route_id to below to achieve your purpose (because as per your code, it seems that you want the results when both of route_id or driver_id falls between the start and end date, however your code checks the driver_id and route_id individually for where condition. You need to wrap them in a where and use nested where in it):

```
if ($request->driverid and $request->routeid) {
    $data->where(function($q) use ($request)
    {
        $q->where('trips.driver_id', '=', $request->driverid)
        ->where('trips.route_id', '=', $request->routeid);
    });
}
```

Comment: really appreciated, but still ignoring Driver filed and just get report by Route

Comment: Ok, I understood that you need the report on basis of both driver and the route not with the or condition. The problem in your code is that it checks the driver_id and route_id individually for where condition. You need to wrap them in a where and use nested where in it, then it will only give the results where both conditions satisfy. Please check my updated solution.